# About Riemann integrability

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

I need to prove if $f$ is continuous on an interval $I$, then its Riemann integral exists.

It is hard for me because it is an interval and not closed interval.

Can anyone give me some answers or clues? Thanks!

It is an exercise from this book: Measure and Integral An introduction to real analysis by Richard L. Wheeden.

[image]

Comment: Take $f(x)=\frac1x$ on $I=(0,1)$. Its Riemann integral does not exist.

Comment: I am confused because it is an exercise in this book: Measure and Integral An introduction to real analysis by Richard L. Wheeden.

Comment: Does the exercise mean closed interval when it says interval?

Comment: I edited it and it is exactly what the exercise says.

Comment: The result is false for intervals in general hence the book *must* mean "closed interval".

Comment: Hint: If $f$ is continious on a closed interval then it's uniformly continuous.

Comment: Read the bottom of the page 11$\,$: $I$ is supposed compact $\dots$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $I$ is compact.

By theorem 1.15 (ii)$\,$ there exist $\;\mathbf x_{1k}\,,\mathbf x_{2k} \in I_k\,$ such that $$U_\Gamma=\sum_{k=1}^N f(\mathbf x_{1k})\,v(I_k)$$ and $$L_\Gamma=\sum_{k=1}^N f(\mathbf x_{2k})\,v(I_k)$$ Theorem 1.15 (iii) assures that for every $\varepsilon>0$ ther exists $\delta>0$ such that $$|f(\mathbf x)-f(\mathbf y)|<\frac \varepsilon {v(I)}$$ if $\;|\mathbf x-\mathbf y|<\delta\,$ and $\,\mathbf x,\mathbf y \in I\,$.

So, if $\,|\Gamma|<\delta$, then $$\inf_{\Gamma}\,U_{\Gamma}-\sup_{\Gamma}\,L_{\Gamma}\, \le \, 
U_{\Gamma}-L_{\Gamma}=\sum_{k=1}^N \;[f(\mathbf x_{1k})-f(\mathbf x_{2k})]\;v(I_k)<\varepsilon$$ because $$v(I)=\sum_{k=1}^N \,v(I_k)$$Since in every case $$\inf_{\Gamma}\,U_{\Gamma}-\sup_{\Gamma}\,L_{\Gamma}\ge 0$$ the arbitrariness of $\varepsilon$ gives $$\inf_{\Gamma}\,U_{\Gamma}=\sup_{\Gamma}\,L_{\Gamma}$$